# How to achieve IP Rate Limiting along with Body Request Rate Limiting in NestJS With Redis?

Tags: redis, nestjs, ip, throttling, node-redis

I was wondering if we can achieve Rate Limiting of IP and Request Body (same some username) separately (Either one if fulfilled should give me Error 429) for same controller function (Route).

Tried Using following **packages** -

```
"nestjs-throttler-storage-redis": "^0.3.0"
"@nestjs/throttler": "^4.0.0",
"ioredis": "^5.3.2"
```

**app.module.ts** -

```
ThrottlerModule.forRoot({
  ttl: process.env.IP_VELOCITY_TTL as unknown as number, // 24 hours in seconds
  limit: process.env.IP_VELOCITY_COUNT as unknown as number, // X number requests per ttl per key (IP address in this case)
  storage: new ThrottlerStorageRedisService(new Redis()),
}),
```

In Respective **Module.ts** -

```
{
  provide: APP_GUARD,
  useClass: ThrottlerGuard,
},
```

**controller.ts** -

```
@Throttle(3, 60 * 60)
```

But this is not sufficient as this is blocking all the requests post 3 times!

Can anybody suggest me to achieve this in Right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to overwrite `ThrottlerGuard` Class like below -

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ThrottlerGuard } from '@nestjs/throttler';

@Injectable()
export class CustomThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
  // Overwritten to handle the IP restriction along with firstName + lastName restriction
  async handleRequest(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    limit: number,
    ttl: number
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    
    const { req, res } = this.getRequestResponse(context);

    // Return early if the current user agent should be ignored.
    if (Array.isArray(this.options.ignoreUserAgents)) {
      for (const pattern of this.options.ignoreUserAgents) {
        if (pattern.test(req.headers['user-agent'])) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    // Tracker for IP
    const tracker = this.getTracker(req);
    const key = this.generateKey(context, tracker);
    const { totalHits, timeToExpire } = await this.storageService.increment(
      key,
      ttl
    );

    // Tracker for firstName and lastName
    const firstNameAndLastNameTracker = this.getNameTracker(req);
    const nameKey = this.generateKey(context, firstNameAndLastNameTracker);
    const { totalHits: totalHitsName, timeToExpire: timeToExpireName } =
      await this.storageService.increment(nameKey, ttl);

    // Throw an error when the user reached their limit (IP).
    if (totalHits > limit) {
      res.header('Retry-After', timeToExpire);
      this.throwThrottlingException(context);
    }

    // Throw an Error when user reached their firstName + lastName Limit.
    if (
      totalHitsName > parseInt(process.env.FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME_MAX_TRY_COUNT)
    ) {
      res.header('Retry-After', timeToExpireName);
      this.throwThrottlingException(context);
    }

    res.header(`${this.headerPrefix}-Limit`, limit);
    // We're about to add a record so we need to take that into account here.
    // Otherwise the header says we have a request left when there are none.
    res.header(
      `${this.headerPrefix}-Remaining`,
      Math.max(0, limit - totalHits)
    );
    res.header(`${this.headerPrefix}-Reset`, timeToExpire);

    return true;
  }

  protected getNameTracker(req: Record<string, any>): string {
    return req.body.firstName + req.body.lastName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create your own guard that `extends ThrottlerGuard` and overrides the [`getTracker` method](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler/blob/c2b2d4661091101bc0b42a3bb4c41cad33f9fb6e/src/throttler.guard.ts#L97) so that it returns this `ip` and `req.body.username` combo. Something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThrottleIpBodyGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {

  getTracker(req: Request) {
    return req.ip + req.body.username;
  }
}
```

Then, instead of `useClass: ThrottlerGuard` you can use `useClass: ThrottleIpBodyGuard`

Comment: This is actually Blocking after 1 Request from the IP also, I have 2 requirements to be worked separately like 1. 3 REQUEST from an IP in 24 hours & 2. 10 Request with having firstName and lastName combination in 24 Hours!